# Auto-Selecting Current Class - Navigation Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay,

So what I am trying to accomplish is having the navigation updated with the "selected" class signifying the page the current end-user is on.

I have tried a multitude of things. But, nothing seems to be working. Here is my code:

**The jQuery:**

```
jQuery(function () {
    var path = location.pathname.substring(1);
    if (path)
        jQuery('.navigation ul li a[href$="' + path + '"]').attr('class', 'selected');
});
```

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="team.html">TEAM</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.navigation li a.selected {
    background: url(../images/navigation-background-active.png) repeat-x;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

If you are confused of what I am asking for... You can view this link:
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Auto-Selecting_Navigation

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I looked at your website and the value of path is `portfolio/newish/index.html`

Probably you should `substring` based on `lastIndexOf` `/`. Try below,

```
jQuery(function () {
    var path = location.pathname; //return /portfolio/newish/index.html
    path = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); //will return index.html

    if (path)
        jQuery('.navigation ul li a[href$="' + path + '"]').addClass('selected');
});
```

Your code looks fine as is, but I think you should use `.addClass` to add a class to an element. Try below,

```
jQuery('.navigation ul li a[href$="' + path + '"]').addClass('selected');
```

Comment: Not sure if that solves your problem or not, but you could probably also shorten your selector to `'.navigation a[href$="' + path + '"]'`

Comment: @MikeTangolics: Welp, neither of those fixed my problem, but they sure did shorten up my code. Thank you!

Comment: @SKS: Thank you, didn't fix it though.

Comment: @AaronBrewer Can you log/alert jQuery('.navigation ul li a[href$="' + path + '"]').length to see if it is returning > 0 also try checking path. .addClass should work if it could select the link.

Comment: @SKS: I have no idea what you are saying lol. But, better solution to your question. You can view my issue, here: http://www.noxinnovations.com/portfolio/newish/

Comment: @AaronBrewer the path was returning the full relative URL, please check my edit to get the last part of the url.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that `location.pathname.substring(1)` is outputting what you expect? That is, `index.html` etc.?

The [path function works](http://jsfiddle.net/CLfsg/7/) (JS adds `show` because of the iframe), and your selector looks correct, so the only thing I can think of is that the path you are expecting it to output is not what is being output on your site.